# RSVP is not chaining 'then' properly

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js

Am I doing something wrong? According to the documentation RSVP.all is supposed to return a promise. And all promises support chainable 'then's. In this example: http://jsbin.com/epuxod/3/edit the first 'then' calls the failed callback properly, but the second 'then' calls the passed callback. I would expect the 2nd 'then' to call the failed callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to return a rejected promise from the first rejection handler in order to pass to the second one.

http://jsbin.com/epuxod/12/edit

I guess if you do nothing, then RSVP assume this is resolved, so it goes the resolve handler.

Comment: Cool, now I know what I'm saying :)